# list on Html.BeginCollectionItem gives error when submitting {get; set;}

Tags: c#, list, model-view-controller

I'm developing an application in MVC without entity framework, this has an object that contains several lists of objects and structs.

I am using html.begincollectionitem() to generate and add new child objects and works fine. The problem appears when submitting.

in this line:

```
[MinLength(1)]
public List<DescCota> CotasFicha { get; set; }
```

"cannot convert object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Productiva.Models.DescCota]' to type 'System.Array'"

Being that the object list that is being converted is precisely that.

This is the code.

Object: "Ficha"

```
public class Ficha
    {
        public int entry { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El nombre de la ficha es obligatorio")]
        public string nombreFicha { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo es obligatorio")]
        public string nombreLargoFicha { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "La imagen es requerida")]
        public string RutaImgFicha { get; set; }
        private byte[] imagenFicha { get; set; }
        public string RutaImgRF { get; set; }
        private byte[] imagenRF { get; set; }
        public string UltimoMensaje;
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime VersionDate { get; set; }
        public int UserSign { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public int UserSign2 { get; set; }
        public string UserName2 { get; set; }

        //Cotas
        [MinLength(1)]
        public List<DescCota> CotasFicha { get; set; }
        //Características Globales
        [MinLength(1)]
        public List<Caracteristica> CaracteristicasFicha { get; set; }
        //Productos Asociados
        [MinLength(1)]
        public List<Producto> ProductosFicha { get; set; }

        private Data.Bdto Bdto;

        #region Constructor

        public Ficha(User U, int _entry)
        {
            //Conector
            Bdto = new Data.Bdto();

            if (_entry == -1)
            {
                entry = SiguienteID();
                nombreFicha = "";
                RutaImgFicha = "";
                imagenFicha = null;
                RutaImgRF = "";
                imagenRF = null;
                UltimoMensaje = "";
                CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                VersionDate = DateTime.Now;
                UserSign = U.UserID;
                UserName = U.UserCode;
                UserSign2 = U.UserID;
                UserName2 = U.UserCode;

                //Listas
                CotasFicha = new List<DescCota>();
                CaracteristicasFicha = new List<Caracteristica>();
                ProductosFicha = new List<Producto>();
            }
            else
            {
                //Conector
                Bdto = new Data.Bdto();

                //Ultimo.
                entry = _entry; //Si es nuevo, debe ser la ultima + 1, agregar
                nombreFicha = "";
                RutaImgFicha = "";
                imagenFicha = null;
                RutaImgRF = "";
                imagenRF = null;
                UltimoMensaje = "";
                CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                VersionDate = DateTime.Now;
                UserSign = U.UserID;
                UserName = U.UserCode;
                UserSign2 = U.UserID;
                UserName2 = U.UserCode;

                //Listas
                CotasFicha = new List<DescCota>();
                CaracteristicasFicha = new List<Caracteristica>();
                ProductosFicha = new List<Producto>();
            }
        }

        public Ficha(User U)
        {
            //Conector
            Bdto = new Data.Bdto();

            entry = SiguienteID();
            nombreFicha = "";
            RutaImgFicha = "";
            imagenFicha = null;
            RutaImgRF = "";
            imagenRF = null;
            UltimoMensaje = "";
            CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
            VersionDate = DateTime.Now;
            UserSign = U.UserID;
            UserName = U.UserCode;
            UserSign2 = U.UserID;
            UserName2 = U.UserCode;

            //Listas
            CotasFicha = new List<DescCota>();
            CaracteristicasFicha = new List<Caracteristica>();
            ProductosFicha = new List<Producto>();
        }

        public Ficha()
        {
            //Conector
            Bdto = new Data.Bdto();

            //Listas
            CotasFicha = new List<DescCota>();
            CaracteristicasFicha = new List<Caracteristica>();
            ProductosFicha = new List<Producto>();
        }

        #endregion

        //Métodos

        #region Imagen
        //Carga Imagen (RF o Ficha)
        public bool LoadImage(System.Drawing.Image Img, bool Ficha)
        {
            bool CargaCorrecta;
            //cargo
            try
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    Img.Save(ms, Img.RawFormat);
                    if (Ficha)
                    {
                        imagenFicha = ms.ToArray();
                        CargaCorrecta = true;
                        //Mensaje de finalizacion
                        UltimoMensaje = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        imagenRF = ms.ToArray();
                        CargaCorrecta = true;
                        //Mensaje de finalizacion
                        UltimoMensaje = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                CargaCorrecta = false;
                UltimoMensaje = e.Message;
            }

            return CargaCorrecta;
        }

        //Retorna Imagen
        public System.Drawing.Image RetornaImagen(bool Ficha)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image Imagen;

            if (Ficha)
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imagenFicha))
                {
                    Imagen = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imagenRF))
                {
                    Imagen = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
                }
            }

            return Imagen;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Cotas

        //Nueva Cota
        public void NuevaCota(string _ID, bool Act, string Nmm)
        {
            DescCota Nueva = new DescCota
            {
                entry = this.entry,
                ID = _ID,
                Activa = Act,
                Nombre = Nmm
            };

            //Agrego a ficha
            CotasFicha.Add(Nueva);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Caracteristicas

        public void NuevaCaracteristica()
        {
            Caracteristica Nueva = new Caracteristica
            {
                entry = this.entry
            };

            CaracteristicasFicha.Add(Nueva);
        }

        public void QuitarCaracteristica(Caracteristica Seleccion)
        {
            CaracteristicasFicha.Remove(Seleccion);
            //El borrar quita de la DB.
        }

        #endregion

        #region Productos

        public void NuevoProducto()
        {
            Producto Nuevo = new Producto
            {
                entry = this.entry
            };

            ProductosFicha.Add(Nuevo);
        }

        public void QuitarProducto(Producto Seleccion)
        {
            ProductosFicha.Remove(Seleccion);
            //Quito de la DB igualmente.
        }

        #endregion

        #region BaseDatos

        //Guardar o Actualizar (Save)
        public void Guardar()
        {

        }

        //OpenID
        private int SiguienteID()
        {
            return Bdto.CC_WEB_SiguienteIDFicha(); 
        }


        #endregion
    }
```

Minor Objects

```
   public struct DescCota
    {
        public int entry { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Identificador es requerido")]
        public string ID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El nombre de la cota es obligatorio")]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public bool Activa { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime VersionDate { get; set; }
        public int UserSign { get; set; }
        public int UserSign2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Producto
    {
        public int entry { get; set; }
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }
        public bool Valid { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public int UserSign { get; set; }

        private Data.Bdto Bdto;

        //Cotas por producto
        List<CotasProducto> Cotas;

        public Producto()
        {
            entry = 0;
            ItemCode = "";
            ItemName = "";

            Cotas = new List<CotasProducto>();
            Bdto = new Data.Bdto();
        }

        public Producto(int ID_)
        {
            entry = ID_;
            ItemCode = "";
            ItemName = "";

            Cotas = new List<CotasProducto>();
            Bdto = new Data.Bdto();
        }

        //Listado de controles (personalizados o no)

        public void GetItem(string Code)
        {
            ItemCode = Code;
            ItemName = Bdto.CC_WEB_GetItemName(Code);
        }

        private string GetItemName(string ItemCode)
        {
            return Bdto.CC_WEB_GetItemName(ItemCode);
        }

        public bool ExisteEnOotroModelo(out string ModelName)
        {
            bool Existe = false;

            ModelName = Bdto.CC_WEB_ValidaSiObjetoExisteEnOtroModelo(ItemCode);

            if(ModelName.Length > 1)
            {
                Existe = true;
            }

            return Existe;
        }
    }

    public struct CotasProducto
    {
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }
        public string IdCota { get; set; }
        public double ValNormal { get; set; }
        public double ValMaximo { get; set; }
        public double ValMinimo { get; set; }

        //Controles por cota
    }

    public struct Caracteristica
    {
        public int entry { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Detalle { get; set; }
    }
```

And the minor objects have their respective partial views, using Html.BeginCollectionItem(). The code is the one that is always used as an example in the case of work with lists.

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $(document).on('change', '.btn-file :file', function () {
        var input = $(this),
            label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
        input.trigger('fileselect', [label]);
    });

    $('.btn-file :file').on('fileselect', function (event, label) {

        var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
            log = label;

        if (input.length) {
            input.val(log);
        } else {
            if (log) alert(log);
        }

    });

    function readURL(input, imgtype) {
        if (imgtype === 'Ficha') {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#img-Ficha').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#img-Rf').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
    }

    $("#imgFicha").change(function () {
        readURL(this, 'Ficha');
    });

    $("#imgRF").change(function () {
        readURL(this, 'RF');
    });

    $("#NuevaCota").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) { $("#Cotas").append(html); }
        });
        return false;
    });

    $("#NuevaCaracteristica").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) { $("#Caracteristicas").append(html); }
        });
        return false;
    });

    $("#NuevoProductoHT").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Ficha/ItemCodeAsoc",
            data: { icode: $("#SrcItemCode").val() },
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $("#Productos").append(html);
                $('#SrcItemCode').val('');
                $('#ShowItemName').val('');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    $("#SrcItemCode").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Ficha/GetItemName',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { icode: $("#SrcItemCode").val() },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    $('#ShowItemName').val(data.P.ItemName);
                }
                else {
                    $('#ShowItemName').val('');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
@model Productiva.Models.DescCota
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Fichas";
}

<div class="LineaCota mt-1">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("DescCota"))
    {
    <div class="form-row mt-1">
        <div class="col-2">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.ID, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text", @placeholder = "Id Cota" })
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Nombre, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text", @placeholder = "Nombre" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto my-1">
            <div class="form-check">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Activa, new { @class = "form-check-input", @type = "checkbox" })
                <label class="form-check-label" for="autoSizingCheck2">
                    Activo?
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

I've been looking for answers for 2 days, I think it's time to ask.
And sorry, my english is not very good.

Comment: What is `Html.BeginCollectionItem`? It's not a standard MVC feature.

Comment: it's a nuget package. I use this as reference: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/